# Powershell aggregation, count items in log file, csv output

Tags: powershell, aggregate

I have a log file that looks as follows:

```
URL       Environment  
127.0.0.1 Prod  
127.0.0.1 Prod  
127.0.0.2 Test  
127.0.0.4 Prod  
127.0.0.2 Test
```

Now I want to aggreate by url and then environment and output it in csv format, so the result should look e.g. like this:

```
URL,Count
127.0.0.1, 2
127.0.0.2, 2  
127.0.0.4, 1
```

and

```
Environment,Count
Prod, 3
Test, 2
```

What's the best way to do that?
I found a solution on a different thread using group-object and measure-object which is similar to this problem though not quite the same.

Comment: How exactly does `Group-Object` not help in this situation? You just need to call it twice assuming you have formatted your input properly. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input file is exactly as you have it display on screen I would do something like this:

```
$inputPath = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$outputPath = "C:\temp\results.txt"

$data = Get-Content $inputPath | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    $splitLine = $_.split(' ',2)
    [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
        URL = $splitLine[0].Trim()
        Environment = $splitLine[1].Trim()
    }
}

$data | Group-Object URL | Select-Object @{Label="URL";Expression={$_.Name}},Count | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content $outputPath
Write-Output "" | Add-Content $outputPath
```

Take the input file and for each line split it on the first space and return only two elements. Trim each split element to make a new object with parameters for `URL` and `Environment`.

Take that `$data` and feed it into `Group-Object` twice. Once for `URL` and once for `Environment`. Feed that data in a csv format to the `$outputPath`.

**Sample Ouput** (contents of `$outputPath`)

```
"URL","Count"
"127.0.0.1","2"
"127.0.0.2","2"
"127.0.0.4","1"

"Environment","Count"
"Prod","3"
"Test","2"
```

I'm sleepy so hopefully I read this one right.

**[ordered]**

If you only have PowerShell 2.0 this keyword wont exist. You can simply remove it from the code and it should work in place. Word of warning. `[ordered]` helps the output appear as coded `Url` then `Environment`. Using the `Select` statement account for that and organizes the output. If you added more fields don't forget to update the 2 `select` statements.

Comment: Hey that's epic, thx!
Just a small addition, there is also a datetime column in the log file, so I wanna convert that to a weekday ("Monday"..) and aggregate by weekday as well. Also the log file has no header column but some random empty lines in between. Anyway I'll try to figure out that bit myself, cheers!

Comment: Actually getting an error when running that code:
[pscustomobject][ordered] <<<<  @{
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ordered:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: @BrentGallagher I am guessing that you have PowerShell 2.0 then? `[ordered]` is a keyword introduced in v3. Easily addressed.